# Handling code-first database migrations that fail halfway

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6

My company has tasked me with figuring out if we want to use EF6 for some new applications. I've done some testing, and I get the general idea of most aspects, but the database updates generated by code-first migrations worry me.

I have a database with 3 tables. A 4th was added, and the 3 existing tables received a foreign key to this table. I generated an update script and ran it. But I made a mistake. This happened:

- The new table was generated.
- The foreign key was added to the first existing table.
- The second table had existing data, and I forgot to specify a default value for the foreign key, so the update failed at this point.

I now have a partially updated database, which to me is a Really Bad Thing. The EF6 system has no idea at this point what it did and did not execute, and if I somehow lose the migration error, neither do I. The only way I could find to fix this was:

- Figure out which update statement cause the error.
- Manually undo the changes in the database that were executed before the faulty statement was hit .
- Run the migration again and hope I got it right this time.

Manually fixing the database was relatively easy, since I only added things. If the migration had for example removed some columns, it would have been way more difficult to revert the changes. Furthermore, a migration like this could very well run without trouble on a development machine that has no data in its tables and suddenly fail when deploying to a testing environment (or worse).

If we are going to use this framework, we need to be sure that there's no way that anyone can accidentally corrupt a database. So my question is: how do people handle issues like these with EF6? Should I just always use the -Script parameter to run the updates manually one by one? Do I just suck it up and triple check all migrations? Is there a better way to deal with this?

I hope the question is clear and I'm looking forward to any insight.

Comment: [This article has good advice on the subject.](https://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/). Also a trick I learned years ago from a good DBA is to always run an update script the first time wrapped in a `BEGIN TRANSACTION ... ROLLBACK` to make sure it executes correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. This makes me wonder why EF6 doesn't wrap its migration scripts in a transaction.